# lp command doesn't run as cron job (according to no log entry

Tags: cron

I need to run this lp command periodically:

```
lp /Users/denniscook/Documents/PrinterManagement/UseInk.pdf 2>&1 >>/Users/denniscook/.cronlogs/runPrinter.log
```

I have this command in runPrinter.zsh script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

cat >>/Users/denniscook/.cronlogs/runPrinter.log <<EOF

***************************
Enter Job `date`
EOF

lp /Users/denniscook/Documents/PrinterManagement/UseInk.pdf 2>&1 >>/Users/denniscook/.cronlogs/runPrinter.log

cat >> /Users/denniscook/.cronlogs/runPrinter.log <<EOF
Exit Job `date`

EOF
```

The lp command is executed correctly when directly issued in terminal, or when the script is issued in terminal- meaning printer prints and log gets updated. But when either the command or the script is run from cron, neither works.

In crontab, I have tried two approaches using the crontab below, commenting out one entry and using the other. The first will run the script, the second attempts to run the command directly.

```
#-----------#
# cron jobs #
#-----------#
#06 11 * * * /Users/denniscook/.scripts/runPrinter.zsh
13 11 * * * lp /Users/denniscook/Documents/PrinterManagement/UseInk.pdf 2>&1 >>/Users/denniscook/.cronlogs/runPrinter.log

~                                                                                                                                       
~
```

When script is executed from terminal, and it works correctly, log entry is:

```
***************************
Enter Job Sun Jan 29 11:07:26 HST 2023
request id is EPSON_WorkForce_845-1286 (1 file(s))
Exit Job Sun Jan 29 11:07:26 HST 2023
```

When cron executes the script, the log entry is as follows (no output from lp cmd):

```
***************************
Enter Job Sun Jan 29 12:15:00 HST 2023
Exit Job Sun Jan 29 12:15:00 HST 2023
```

When cron executes lp command directly,there is no log entry.

I don't know what difference there is between cron executing the job, and my executing them in terminal.  My research failed to find an answer.

I appreciate any help...

Comment: You need to change the order of redirections to `>>/Users/denniscook/.cronlogs/runPrinter.log 2>&1` (in both cases) if you want to capture any errors from the lp command

Comment: Have you tried to pass the full path to the `lp` binary?   your cron has no idea about your environment and doesn't know your `PATH` env variable.  So try that first and also to debug your cron, don't pass `2>&1`

Comment: With `2>&1` first, cron should capture the leaking output, and send it to your Linux email account: you might see them there.

Comment: @ValentinBajrami  It can't hurt to do this, but `man cron` claims to set up `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin` (should find `lp`), along with `SHELL= /bin/sh`, LOGNAME and HOME (both taken from `/etc/passwd`). Granted, "it works in terminal but not on cron" is a .profile problem 70% of the time.

Comment: PROBLEM RESOLVED, thanks to your-all's help.  Bottom line: cron has to be added to full disc access.  The suggestion to reorder the redirect resulted in the error message "/usr/bin/lp: Operation not permitted" being written in log file. Google search "lp command in crontab on mac not permitted" resulted in a number of hits that pointed out the need for cron to be in full disc access.  Thank you all for your timely responses.

Comment: JUST DISCOVERED: I guess this print job could be scheduled using the MAC application AUTOMATOR. I was thinking Apple would make job scheduling available to normal MAC user, who isn't expected to have knowledge of linux or scripts. Sure enough, when I googled it, the hits were about the AUTOMATOR app. Personally, I think I prefer cron.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the cron process doesn't have full disk access.

Solution:

- Go to Settings > Security & Privacy then select "Full Disk Access" in the list on the left.
- Click the plus button to add a new app.
- In the file browser type a forward slash to switch into direct entry mode. Enter the path `/usr/sbin/cron`. (found it by typing 'which cron' on the terminal)

Alternatively use Automator instead of cron. (If you want to learn a new tool, but that sounds annoying...)

*(This answer was in the comments, and I'm just posting it here as a formal answer so the next person doesn't have to read all the comments to get the answer. Thanks for gpaCook for sharing the final solution.)*